Nested Array rendering issue in Flatlist react native
I am working in react native project
[
  [
{
  "id": 1,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 7,
  "isDefaultViewVisible": true,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": true,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
  }
 ],
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": false,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
},
{
  "id": 7,
  "isDefaultViewVisible": true,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isVisible": true,
  "localFileName": null,
  "maintenance_assets_id": null,
  "name": null,
  "thumb_name": null
}
]

]
Above is my nested array and I am working in gallery fetch feature with multimedia selection image or videos so for fetch data from gallery as below
const getFromGallery = async (type: string, index: any, mediaParentIndex?: any) => {

setRefreshList(true);
globals
  .getMediaFromGalleryFunction(type, mediaUploadLimit - 1)
  .then((response: any) => {
    
    response?.assets?.map((data: any) => {
      const modifiedData = { ...data, media_from: 2 };
      let multipleMediaUploadSupportData = {
        name: `${modifiedData?.uri}`,
        thumb_name: `${modifiedData?.uri}`,
        localFileName: `${modifiedData?.uri}`
      }
      updateMediaProperties(mediaFromGalleryValue, mediaParentIndex, index, multipleMediaUploadSupportData);
      if (data?.type.includes('image')) {
        // mediaFromGalleryValue[index] = modifiedData;
        newImageValue[index] = undefined;
        unSavedInspectionFunc(index, true);
        handleInputChange(localCountArray);
        newVideoValue[index] = undefined;
        setRefreshList(!refreshList);
      } else {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && (data.uri.includes('mov') || data.uri.includes('MOV'))) {
          globals
            .convertMOVToMP4Func(data)
            .then((results: any) => {
              mp4Filename = results.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
              urlFinal = results;
            })
            .catch((e: any) => { });
        }
         newVideoValue[index] = undefined;
        unSavedInspectionFunc(index, true);
        handleInputChange(localCountArray);
        newImageValue[index] = undefined;
        setRefreshList(false);
      }

    });
   })
   .catch(e => {
    console.log('getFromGallery Error ==>> ', e);
   });
 };

My Flatlist
<FlatList
            renderItem={(mediaItem) => renderUploadAttachmentCardFunc(mediaItem, item.index)}
            data={mediaFromGalleryValue[item.index]?.filter((multipleMediaItem: any) => multipleMediaItem?.isVisible) || []}
            keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id}
            numColumns={2}
            extraData={refreshList}
          />

My feature is I need to upload 6 images for one particular item and 7th position is browse component in every item in my initial nested array. Now When I select 6 images one by one at that time above code working fine no issue but if I select multiple images at a same time at that time it create problem and UI is not rendering properly it means some time render one image and replace with exiting one so any idea how I can solve this in react native nested array render images from gallery with multi selection ?
